# When should I use @Immutable in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Where should I place [Immutable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Immutable) annotation to enable composition optimizations ? 1, 2 or/and 3 and why ?

It confused me that standart VisualTransformation interface for TextField has this annotation, but PasswordVisualTransformation doesn't and @Immutable is not inherited

```
// 1 - @Immutable
sealed class State(val option1: String) {

    // 2 - @Immutable
    object One : State("")

    // 3 - @Immutable
    data class Two(val option2: String) : State("")
}

@Composable
fun Screen(state: State) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is sufficient. You can double check this using [compose compiler metrics report](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md) or [skipped recompositions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#recomposition-counts) and changing:

```
data class Two(val option2: String) : State("")
```

to

```
data class Two(var option2: String) : State("")
```

Using var will make sure to mark Two as unstable by the compiler, so you will see the benefit of @Immutable annotation. Without this change - composable will be marked as skippable and stable anyway, so you won't notice any difference.

Also there is no need to mark classes as Stable/Immutable unless you create a library for someone to use or have multi-module project

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add it to the first one (top level sealed class).